# Simple graphical text display?

Tags: python, windows

Hey everybody,
I have a script that reads a value from the Windows registry and I need a pretty way to display it on my second monitor. It's just an integer. I want to be able to choose a size in pixels and color. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: You won't be able to change the font-size from Python, but you can just apply console colors to the text. If you *must* have a huge font size, find a GUI toolkit (I use PyQt4, but it's a bit heavyweight for something like this).

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to install a GUI library for what you need to do, Tkinter is already in python windows, example:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
label = Tk.Label(None, text='The text you want to display', font=('Times', '18'),fg='blue')
label.pack()
label.mainloop()
```

just refresh the label every certain amount of time